# Is it possible to disable previous dates of a datetimepicker according to selected date in other datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using two datetimepickers for startdate and enddate.I want to disable all the previous date in endadate when i select date in startdate.For example if i select 29/04/2020 in startdate than in enddate all dates before 29/04/2020 must be disabled.
below is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy  hh:ii',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true,

    });
    $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

How do i modify the code to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code, it is working.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing Date Time Picker</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <label>Start Date: </label>
 <input id="startDate" type="text" />
 <label>End Date: </label>
 <input id="endDate" type="text" />
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd-m-Y H:i',
    closeOnDateSelect:true,
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
     //need to convert date to format yyyy/m/d
     var val = $input.val();
     $('#endDate').datetimepicker({minDate: val, formatDate:'d-m-Y H:i'});
    }
   });
   $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd-m-Y H:i',
    closeOnDateSelect:true,
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: even though i have copied the above code i am unable to get the same result.

Comment: If you run above code as code snippet here, does it work?

Comment: i am using this code with codeigniter. can this issue be because of codeigiter.

Comment: Can you please match your datetimepicker library and the one I am using here? and can you share your full code snippet so that I can see why it's not working.

Comment: well I guess my answer solved the original question issue, if you update your question with the exact code piece. Maybe I can be of help.

Comment: Its working now.i guess there was issues with datetimepicker library.

Comment: Good. Now can you please this accept this as an Answer?

Comment: Hey i am facing problem when i change format to 'd-m-yy H:i'.as i want t pass time along with date.